# Missing uids in GPG public key after importing secret key

Tags: linux, gpg

I want to import my keypair from my current Linux machine to a new one that is going to replace it. Thus, I exported the secret and imported it to the new using `ssh`:

```
gpg --export --secret-key -a | ssh new_machine gpg --import -a
```

Listing the secret key in the new machine gives identical results with the output on the old (even when using the `--list-packets` option).

However, the public key listing differs between the two machines; I get only 2 associated uids in the new machine while on the old there are 4 uids:

```
# old machine
$ gpg -k
pub   4096R/XXXXXXXX 2020-12-31 [expires: 2022-05-31]
uid                  John Doe (John) <john.doe@mail1.com>
uid                  John Doe (John) <john.doe@mail2.com>
uid                  John Doe (John) <john.doe@mail3.com>
uid                  John Doe (John) <john.doe@mail4.com>
sub   4096R/YYYYYYYY 2020-12-31 [expires: 2022-12-31]

# new machine (after import)
$ gpg -k
pub   4096R/XXXXXXXX 2020-12-31 [expires: 2022-05-31]
uid                  John Doe (John) <john.doe@mail1.com>
uid                  John Doe (John) <john.doe@mail2.com>
sub   4096R/YYYYYYYY 2020-12-31 [expires: 2022-12-31]
```

Manually adding a uid with `--edit` that matches one of the *missing* ones, causes duplicate (and identical?) uids in the private key.

So, starting over with the import, I perform the same steps but also export the public key from the old machine and insert it in the new one, which seems to work.
The output from the import operation is:

```
gpg: key XXXXXXXX: "John Doe (John) john.doe@mail3.com" 2 new user IDs
gpg: key XXXXXXXX: "John Doe (John) john.doe@mail4.com>" 2 new signatures
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:           new user IDs: 2
gpg:         new signatures: 2
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   1  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 1u
gpg: next trustdb check due at 2022-12-31
```

and the result of `--list-keys` is as in the old machine with all 4 uids.

So, I have the following questions:

1. I was under the impression that exporting a secret key and, subsequently, importing it to a new store, adds all the associated uids to the public key as well. Why was I missing 2 out of 4 uids? Did I disregard something in the initial store?
2. (depending on the answer of 1 above) What is the correct way to import and export a keypair? Why did I have to export/import the public key separately?

PS: My issue sounds a bit like the reverse of the uid-related problem described [here](https://tribaal.io/restoring-privkey-uid-from-pubkey-uid.html) (uid present in public key but missing in private key).

Comment: *"Listing the secret key in the new machine gives identical results with the output on the old"* ... do you mean that on the new machine `gpg -K` will show all 4 user ids while `gpg -k` will only show 2?

Comment: @fuzzydrawings yes, that is it.

Comment: I am unable to imagine how this can occur, as `gpg -K` (aka `list-secret-keys`) is only a filtered version of `gpg -k` (aka `list-keys`) to show corresponding secret keys. What version of `gpg` is on the new machine?

Comment: @fuzzydrawings the version on the new machine is 1.4.23. However, since then, I tried exactly the same steps on a 3rd machine with gpg2 and they work just fine. Is there any verbose output option for import? `-v` wasn't very illuminating. Maybe there's something there if such output exists, but not sure if I'll have the energy to repeat the whole process all over again.

Comment: The 1.4 branch of GnuPG is only minimally maintained (last update was in 2018) and really shouldn't be used anymore unless you require compatibility with ancient PGP software from the 1990's. The way it stores and processes key material is significantly different than version 2, so quirks like this are bound to occur from time to time. As for verbose output, you can try `-vvv` or if you're really feeling adventurous you can use the `--debug-all` flag.

Comment: @fuzzydrawings I see, thanks for that. It will take me a bit to revisit this, but I'll feel mostly curious than adventurous. I'll see if I can spot anything in the debug output and report back.